# How to create a JSONObject in Android (it keeps forgetting)?

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to create a JSONObject in my Android project. It seems to work, but it only seems to remember the last thing I put into it. This code:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
try {
    json.put("text", "thi sis the message");
    json.put("customer_uuid", customer_uuid);
    Log.wtf(json.toString(), "asassa");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.wtf("WTF", e);
}
```

Prints out `{"customer_uuid": "123"}`. But when I erase the line in which the customer_uuid is put in, it only prints out `{"text", "thi sis the message"}`.

Why does it only remember the last thing I put in? And more importantly, how do I make it store both the things? All tips are welcome!

Comment: We would need to see a little bit more of the surrounding code to see what's going on.

Comment: What else do you need to know more? The rest around it is totally unrelated. I just want to create aJSONObject and then print it out. Would you know how to do that?

Comment: define `it keeps forgetting`

Comment: because you are creating a new object entirely each time?

Comment: i don't get it. you don't put the line with the customer_uuid, and you are surprised not to see it in the json string?

Comment: @njzk2 he means only the second key-value pair is added by "forgetting".

Comment: also, given the answer given, I have serious doubts that the output is literally `{"text", "thi sis the message"}`.

Comment: Yeah, this code outputs both of the key-value pairs, unless the `customer_uuid` variable is **`null`**. Also it is in proper JSON format. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to Log.wtf("asassa", json.toString());

Your tag may not be that long so it gets truncated. See the [reference page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) for more details.

Comment: I still don't get what was wrong, but it seems that this was the problem. Pretty stupid of me. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

Your code is okay, but you log it wrong. Don't use the *tag* for logging (first parameter), use the *message* (second):

```
Log.wtf("SOME_TAG", json.toString());
```

Also be sure that the `customer_uuid` variable is not **`null`**, unless it will not be added into your JSON.

Answer (score 2):

jsonObject.toString(2);

human-readable string